# probability, need help to differentiate distinct or non-distinct

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am having trouble to understand the problems based on combinatorics. In particular, I don't understand when to think in terms of disctinct object or non-disctinct object.

Here is one question:

Five distinct families arive to a party. Each family consists of 3 people. The 15 participants of the party are arranged randomly in a line.

a) what is the probability that members of the smith family sit next to each other?
b) what is the probability that all the members of the Smith family sit next to each other but not all members from the Johnson's family sit next to each other.

**The part I don't understand is whether to treat the entire family as distinct such that we have AAABBB or each family member is distinct such that A1A2A3 B1B2B3 ?**

Comment: Each family members are distinct.

Comment: Can you please explain why

Comment: Are your family members all "same"? :). Persons are always taken to be distinct, even if say there are two identical twins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have three colored blocks: red, blue, yellow. If you wanted to arrange them in order, you have $3! = 6$ ways of doing so. This is because you can *distinguish* between the different blocks (by color).

If you had three red blocks, there would only be one way of arranging them in order, because you cannot *distinguish* one block from another. You could switch any blocks around but you can never tell.

It's possible that you can tell a different way, for example by size or shape. However, in the context of the problem we were not given this information, so we cannot assume anything. This makes the objects indistinguishable in the context of the problem.

When tackling combinatorics problems, you should think about the criteria you're using. If you're talking about people, and you care about who they are by name, they are probably all distinguishable. If you don't care about their names and only about something about them, then they could be indistinguishable based on that criteria. Just make sure you're consistent within your domain/whatever you choose.

Let's tackle part a of this problem with both methods. It asks for a probability, so let's find the total number of arrangements and the arrangements we want and divide.

---

**Distinguishable:**

Total number of arrangements: Each person is identified by name. So, we have $15!$ ways of ordering them.

Arrangements we want: We treat the family as a block, so we have $15-3+1 = 13$ objects to order. However, we need to multiply this by $3! = 6$ because there are that many ways to order within the family as well, making the total $6\times{13!}$. Notice how because each person is distinguishable by name, we have to treat them all as different objects.

Probability: $\frac{6\times{13!}}{15!} = \frac{1}{35}$

**Indistinguishable:**

Total number of arrangements: We only care about whether or not someone is part of the Smith family. So we split the people into these two groups and order them. Within each group, they are indistinguishable because we can only tell people apart based on the criteria we set (whether or not they're in the Smith family). We have $\binom{15}{3}$ ways of ordering all of the people.

Arrangements we want: Again, we treat the family as one block. However, we can't distinguish any of the other people from each other. Why? The only criteria for telling them apart is whether or not they are part of the Smith family, and none of them are part of the Smith family. We have $\binom{13}{1} = 13$ arrangements.

Probability: $\frac{13}{\binom{15}{3}} = \frac{13\cdot{6}}{15\cdot{14}\cdot{13}} = \frac{1}{35}$

---

As you can see, it doesn't matter which method we choose here, as long as we are consistent with our criteria. Sometimes it's easier to use one method over the other, but here it turns out that indistinguishable people makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

For (a), we group the Smith family together as a unit: $\{a, b, c\}$, and we treat this unit as one person. Each unit within the Smith family is unique- the mother, the father, and the child. So we have $13$ units to permute, which gives us $13!$ arrangements with the Smith family sitting together. However, we now have to take into account ordering the Smith family, which is done in $3!$ ways. By rule of product, we multiply: $3! * 13!$. Then we divide out by the number of ways to permute $15$ people, which is $15!$. That's your probability.

So we think of each person as unique, as each person can be named, or uniquely identified. If you have a dozen unlabeled ping pong balls, do you really differentiate them in any way? Or do you just care that they're ping pong balls? That's the intuition for understanding the differences.

Do you need help with (b) as well, or is this good to get you started?