# Why is Binomial Probability used here?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> A test consists of 10 multiple choice questions with five choices for each question.  As an experiment, you GUESS on each and every answer without even reading the questions.
>   What is the probability of getting exactly 6 questions correct on this test?

The answer says:

> $$P = \binom{10}{6} (0.2)^6 (0.8)^4$$

I was thinking though:

$$P(A \text{and} B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$$

Probability of getting $6$ right and $4$ wrong would be just:

$$(0.2)^6 (0.8)^4$$

Why is the binomial coefficient used there?

Comment: Your product  is the probability of getting $6$ **specific** questions right, and the rest wrong.  We have to add up terms  like yours, over all choices of $6$ questions.

Comment: In your calculation, what do you think the events A and B are ?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, but then when do we **not** use the coefficient? Would you mind looking here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356879/why-dont-by-multiply-by-binomnk-here? Its the more deep question.

Comment: I cannot understand your question there. You solved the problem in a correct and clear way, then want to mess up the answer. Your numerator already counts the number of ways to choose $2$ all-stars and $3$ half-stars.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, but what about the order of selection?

Comment: There is no order of selection.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, if you pick the first all star-and the 3rd allstar, if you pick the 2nd allstar and the third all star?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heropup gave a really good answer, but let me expand on this a bit for you to give you a bit of a deeper understanding from a different perspective.

We know that the total probability for any event happening for all cases must be $1$. If the problem was solved the way you presented, would the total probabilities add up to $1$? Clearly not.

Let's look at each individual question, which by itself has probabilities that add up to one. For a particular question, getting it right is a $0.2$ chance and getting it wrong is a $0.8$ chance, a total of $1$. If we go question by question, we take the probability to a power, so let's do that with the total probability:

$$
\begin{align*}
(0.8 + 0.2) &= 0.8 + 0.2 \\
(0.8 + 0.2)^2 &= 0.8^2 + 2 (0.8)(0.2) + 0.2^2 \\
(0.8 + 0.2)^3 &= 0.8^3 + 3 (0.8)^2(0.2) + 3 (0.8)(0.2)^2 + 0.2^3 \\
(0.8 + 0.2)^4 &= 0.8^4 + 4 (0.8)^3(0.2) + 6 (0.8)^2(0.2)^2 + 4 (0.8)(0.2)^3 + 0.2^4
\end{align*}$$

And so on and so forth. This is a direct application of the binomial theorem:
$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k}
$$
for $x = 0.8$ and $y = 0.2$.

Comment: (+1) but $$\binom{10}{6}$$ Means how man ways of choosing $6$ out of $10$ such that order of picking does not matter though?

Comment: Yes, because when you expand $(0.8+0.2)^{10}$ you get $\binom{10}{6}$ ways of obtaining the term $(0.8)^6(0.2)^4$. The order in which you choose one term from each power of $(0.8+0.2)$ does not matter, since they are just all multiplied together.

Comment: and then when do we not multiply by $\binom{n}{k}$. Would you take a look at:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356879/why-dont-by-multiply-by-binomnk-here please?

Comment: That's a bit of a vague question. What I think you're asking is how to determine when to use binomial coefficients. I have a response to a different question which may help provide insight: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758581/probability-need-help-to-differentiate-distinct-or-non-distinct/758658#758658

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that **order matters**.

The long answer begins with an example.  Suppose you had only 3 questions, and each question was True/False, so you have equal probabilities of answering any given question correctly by random guessing.  Then you can easily enumerate the possible outcomes of whether or not you get Questions 1, 2, or 3 correct.  Let the ordered triplet $(q_1, q_2, q_3)$ represent the outcomes of questions $1, 2, 3$ in that order, where $q_i \in \{R, W\}$ where $R$ indicates a right answer, and $W$ indicates a wrong answer.  Then your outcomes are $$\begin{align*}  (R, R, R) \\ (R, R, W) \\ (R, W, R) \\ (R, W, W) \\ (W, R, R) \\ (W, R, W) \\ (W, W, R) \\ (W, W, W) \end{align*}$$ and now it is obvious that there are $8$ elementary outcomes.  If I asked you what the probability is of getting **exactly** 2 correct answers out of three, you would say $3/8$.  But your method of reasoning for the original question would have given $(1/2)^3 = 1/8$, which is clearly not the case.

So why is your method not correct?  Because there are, in general, $\binom{n}{k}$ arrangements of $k$ correct answers out of $n$ questions, and each distinct *ordering* of correct/incorrect answers is a distinct elementary outcome.

Comment: $\binom{10}{6}$ Means how many ways of choosing 6 out of 10 such that order of picking does not matter though? (+1)

Comment: You're confusing the "order of picking" with the order of question.  $\binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of ways to choose $k$ items out of $n$, when the ordering of the $k$ items chosen does not matter, so for example, there are $\binom{10}{6}$ ways to choose $6$ distinct integers from $\{1, 2, \ldots, 10\}$.  But such a choice corresponds to the **question numbers** for which correct answers are given.  The "order" I refer to in my answer above refers to this order, in the sense that answering the first 6 questions correctly is a distinct outcome from answering the last 6 questions correctly.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the meaning of the order does not matter in this $\binom{n}{k}$ generally? The order in which you take the $k$ objects?

Comment: That is correct:  If I have $n = 5$ True/False questions numbered $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, and I want to count the number of ways that exactly $3$ of these questions are answered correctly, then I have the outcomes $$\begin{align*} & \{1, 2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 4\}, \{1, 2, 5\}, \{1, 3, 4\}, \{1, 3, 5\}, \\ &\{1, 4, 5\}, \{2, 3, 4\}, \{2, 3, 5\}, \{2, 4, 5\}, \{3, 4, 5\}. \end{align*}$$  The order in which I select which of the three questions are correct is not important:  $\{1, 2, 3\} = \{3, 1, 2\}$, for example.  But the order of which questions are correct/incorrect **does** matter.

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment, each of the above $10$ outcomes has a one-to-one correspondence to an ordering of True/False:  e.g., $\{1, 3, 4\}$ corresponds to the outcome $(T, F, T, T, F)$, and vice versa.  The ordering of the numbers in the set $\{1, 3, 4\}$ doesn't matter, but the ordering of "T" and "F" in the $5$-tuple $(T, F, T, T, F)$ does matter, since the ordering $(T, F, T, F, T)$ would correspond to $\{1, 3, 5\}$, not $\{1, 3, 4\}$.

Comment: One last question, but why do we multiply by $\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: Is it just because of casework? $P(A) + P(B)  +P(C)$?

Answer (score 0):

You've now calculated the probability that you are first right 6 times and then wrong 4 times. But you could of course also have a different combination like right 5 times, then wrong 4 times and then right again. The binomial coefficient gives you the amount of combinations you could have.