# Why don't by multiply by $\binom{n}{k}$ here?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[A while ago,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353044/why-is-binomial-probability-used-here/) I asked why we multiply by $\binom{n}{k}$. Take this question:

> At a soccer match there are 230 all-stars and 220 half-stars. You pick five people from the crowd. What is the probability that exactly two are all-stars?

I would solve it like this:

> $$P = \frac{\binom{230}{2} \cdot \binom{220}{3}}{\binom{450}{5}}$$

Now, here is the question:

> Let the all-stars chosen be denoted $\{A_{i},A_{j}\}$ and the half-stars chosen be denoted $\{H_{k},H_{\ell},H_{m}\}$. Why don't we multiply the probability by $\binom{230}{2}$ again, since the picked two may be $(A_{5},A_{83})$ or $(A_{142},A_{77})$, or something like that?

Comment: @Winther The people. $a_1$ is the first all-star, $h_1$ is the first half-star etc..

Comment: @Winther I have edited the question to clarify the source of the confusion (as I understand it). OP, please check to see if I understand your question (assuming the edit is accepted).

Answer (score 2):

Because you originally used combinations (${}_{230}C_{2}$), not permutations (${}_{230}P_{2}$), your numerator ${}_{230}C_{2}\cdot{}_{220}C_{3}$ is already the number of ways to pick two all-stars and three half-stars not counting permutations. If your had instead used ${}_{230}P_{2}\cdot{}_{220}P_{3}$ as your numerator, you would need to account for the fact that you were counting each combination multiple times (once for each pair of permutations of the all-stars and of the half-stars). Then you'd want to divide by ${}_{2}P_{2}\cdot{}_{3}P_{3}=2!\cdot3!$, which is the number of ways to order two all-stars and three half-stars.